# JS .replace(str, str): how to get a variable in parameter 1 yet work globally?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a sentence such :

```
Visit5Our3Mini4Lab3!
```

I want to add a separation "_" after each digit. My digit are always <6 , so I only have one-digit numbers.

I found a way to loop that from 0 to 5, so on the first turn I replace all "0", then all "1", etc. This unfortunately only replace the FIRST occurrence of my digit (not global).

```
for (i=0; i<6; i++) { str = str.replace(i, i+"_"); // this work once only
```

Is there a way to use `.replace()` with a variable `i` yet global ?

```
for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) { str = str.replace(/i/g, i+"_"); // replace all characters "i", NOT what I want.
```

How to get a variable in 1st parameter of .replace(), yet get it working globally.

http://jsfiddle.net/qyWga/3/

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

---

Edit: I also tried :

```
for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) { 
    var trick = "/"+i+"/g";
    trick = trick.toString(); 
    str = str.replace(trick, i+"_");
}
```

It doesn't works. Any other trick ?

Comment: yes there is, but you'd be far better off instead using a regex that will find them all without using said loop.

Comment: my trouble is I want to replace "0" by "0_", "1" by "1_", etc. Is there a duo of regex allowing that ?

Comment: Yes, regexp can do that.

Comment: I used `.replace(/([0-6])/g, $1+"_");` before. Oh Coding! >[PEBCAK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_error)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use regular expressions, with the `g` (global) flag:

```
str = str.replace(/([0-6])/g, "$1_");
```

This uses parentheses to capture the match, the match is formed of any number from `0`-`6` (inclusive of the `0` and the `6`), the `g` searches for *every* match in the whole of the string. the `$1` represents the first captured-match, and puts that into the replacement along with the `_` that follows.

Comment: Oh. There is the duo regex I was looking for. No loop needed.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use a function!

```
"Visit5Our3Mini4Lab3!".replace(/\d/g, function(match) { return match + "_"; });
```

Output

```
"Visit5_Our3_Mini4_Lab3_!"
```

Checkout the [String.prototype.replace docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) for more info

Comment: @Hugolpz, what is "funny" about this answer?

Comment: funny / witty / surprising : using match+ , you attack the same question from a different point.

Comment: I just prefer things that use the least amount of magic as possible, that's all.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
str = str.replace(/\d/g, "$&_");
```

This is described at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: the shortest way <°)))))))> +1.